# Push Notification with firebase and swift ui not working

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

So I went through all the steps to implement push notifications using FCM, but for some reason, I can't figure out why it won't work. I swear it was working yesterday, but for some reason today the notification won't go through. Also, I have my APN Auth key uploaded in firebase aswell. Here is the code I use:

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseAuth
import Firebase 
import FirebaseMessagingInterop
import FirebaseMessaging
import UserNotifications



class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
  let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
      FirebaseApp.configure()

      Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

      if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
          options: authOptions,
          completionHandler: {_, _ in })
      } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
        UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
      }

      application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
      return true
  }

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                   fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
      print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    print(userInfo)

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
  }
}


@main

struct YourApp: App {
// register app delegate for Firebase setup
@UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate


var body: some Scene {
  WindowGroup {
    NavigationView {
        
       ContentView()
            
    
    }
  }
}
}



extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate {
  func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {

    let deviceToken:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken ?? ""]
      print("Device token: ", deviceToken) // This token can be used for testing notifications on FCM
  }
}

@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

// Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
  withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
  let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

  if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
      print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
  }

  print(userInfo)

  // Change this to your preferred presentation option
  completionHandler([[.banner, .badge, .sound]])
}

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

  }

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {

  }

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
  let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo

  if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
    print("Message ID from userNotificationCenter didReceive: \(messageID)")
  }

  print(userInfo)

  completionHandler()
}
}
```

Comment: Did u changed anything?

Comment: @Kudos thanks for the comment. Do you mean in my code or on Firebase? To my knowledge I haven't changed anything.

Comment: "Not Working" is a bit broad. Did you perform any troubleshooting by stepping through the code line by line, examining the flow and vars along the way until you find something unexpected? Is the code responding at all? What line isn't working? Where does the code start to fail? I notice you have no error handling or other code within a couple of those functions - if they fire, the code would silently fail and you'd never know why. Please update the question.

Answer (score 1):

In your Info.plist, set FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to "NO". I believe this adjustment will be help for you.